# Is ACK message redundant for an self-defined protocol over TCP connection?

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols

The project I am working on defines an application-level protocol over TCP, for passing messages between client and server. It defines an ACK message (with message ID) that is sent by the client to server when it receives a message.

I am wondering if such a message is redundant over TCP, if the only purpose it serves is to notify the server that the message is received?

Is there any protocol over TCP that defines an ACK message?

Comment: The fact that the packets were received at the destination doesn't guarantee that the application-level software on the destination computer actually picked up the message, much less that it did something meaningful with that message. The kind of "ACK message" you describe could tell you this.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thanks for such a succinct answer!